# tableview is nil and the app crashes ios xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, tableview

IN my program,I am setting the constraints for my view using nslayoutconstraints.the view consists of a tableview,collectionview and a main view.When the view is loaded,the app crashes with the following error

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

*** First throw call stack:
(0x27126d67 0x34c61c77 0x27047237 0x2704701b 0xe1333 0xe0bc1 0x1c6ca7 0x1d24e1 0x9b59cb 0x9b59b7 0x9b9411 0x270ecc41 0x270eb361 0x27038981 0x27038793 0x2e3e8051 0x2a62a981 0x1d72b5 0x351fdaaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

The value of the tableview is "NIL"

```
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"tableView":_tableView,
                                  @"mainView": _mainView,
                                  @"movieDetail":_movieDetailView
                                  };
```

This dictionary is used to set the height constraint in the tableview as below

```
NSArray *constraint_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[tableView(tableHeight)]"
                                                                options:0
                                                                metrics:metrics
                                                                  views:viewsDictionary];

[_tableView addConstraints:constraint_V];
```

Why is it that the value of tableview is nil?This tablview is an IBOUTLET from storyboard.When i allocate memory programatically the code runs.but the tableview is not loaded with data.Can anyone get me the reason?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you doublechecked that the UITableView is really connected with that property?

Comment: Yes it is.The same tableview when called from a different page works perfectly.You have any idea why it happens?

Comment: I'm afraid not without more context. Like rstewart mentioned below: where is this code executed? Further I don't get the point what you mean with: "When i allocate memory programatically the code runs.but the tableview is not loaded with data." Would you be able to share some example project?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not calling this too early and the table view has not yet been created. Perhaps you are executing this code in "viewDidLoad", maybe try viewWillAppear, or viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: viewDidLoad would be the perfect fit for this: "This method is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory. This method is called regardless of whether the view hierarchy was loaded from a nib file or created programmatically in the loadView method.".

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you're synthesizing correctly to that property.

```
@synthesize yourIBOutletTableView = _tableView;
```

Comment: At least, if the IBOutlet's name is "tableView" like in the UITableViewController, there is no need to synthesize here.